# Azure Cosmos DB JavaScript SDK version 1.x - deprecated or unusable?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

We are currently using Azure Cosmos DB JavaScript SDK version: 1.14.4. We received an email stating that this version will be retiring in August 2020. Point of clarification - will this version be completely unusable after August 2020, or will it just be deprecated and no longer supported with bug fixes, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

The npm deprecation message is more accurate https://www.npmjs.com/package/documentdb. Code using the documentdb SDK will still continue to function beyond August

Answer (score 1):

This is what mentioned in the [Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-node/issues/257)

> We have recently announced deprecation version 1.x of the Azure Cosmos
>   JavaScript SDK. We will end support for the documentdb package and
>   this repo on August 30, 2020. Please update to our new package
>   @azure/cosmos as soon as possible. If you encounter any issues, you
>   can raise them in the Azure central SDK repo. If something is
>   preventing you from upgrading to the latest version of the SDK, you
>   can always email me directly: stfaul@microsoft.com